# Errors thrown in angular 6 resolver lose error custom type

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, angular6

I'm trying to throw custom errors in my resolvers that I catch with my global error handler. I can throw errors in a component and they come through fine, but when I throw them in the resolver their type is changed to the standard `Error` type.

Here is a functioning repro:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-vvgys6

**Setup**

```
class DisplayableError extends Error {
// ...
}


@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService {
  constructor() { }

  handleError(error) {

    console.log('GOT ERROR instance of DisplayableError', error instanceof DisplayableError);

  }
}
```

**Working usage**

in any component I can just throw an error and it's caught in the global error handler and it is an instance of `DisplayableError`.

```
throw new DisplayableError('blah');
```

**Broken usage**

When I throw the error in the resolver the instance type is changed to `Error` and `instanceof DisplayableError` returns false.

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreGetResolver implements Resolve<StoreModel> {
  constructor(
    private storeService: StoreService,
  ) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<StoreModel> {

    let storeId = route.paramMap.get('storeId');
    return this.storeService.get(storeId)
      .catch(error => Observable.throw(new DisplayableError('my custom error')));
  }

}
```

I've also tried this

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<StoreModel> {

  let storeId = route.paramMap.get('storeId');
  return this.storeService.get(storeId)
    .do(
      () => { },
      error => throw new DisplayableError('my custom error')
    );
}
```

...and even this

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<StoreModel> {
  throw new DisplayableError('my custom error');

}
```

The constructor for DisplayableError is called with the correct data and the message even makes it to the global error handler, but the the error is of type `Error` instead of `DisplayableError` when it gets there

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with Typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965

The workaround is to do some fiddling with the prototype:

```
// Use this class to correct the prototype chain.
export class MyError extends Error {
    __proto__: Error;
    constructor(message?: string) {
        const trueProto = new.target.prototype;
        super(message);

        // Alternatively use Object.setPrototypeOf if you have an ES6 environment.
        this.__proto__ = trueProto;
    }
}
```